# Installing Ubuntu on 710S-13IKB IdeaPad Laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, bios, lenovo-laptop

I am trying to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on my new laptop - Ideapad 710S-13IKB. Unfortunately, as I boot Ubuntu from USB, and proceeded to the drive selection Window, Ubuntu could not detect my entire [SSD](http://ark.intel.com/products/94921/Intel-SSD-600p-Series-256GB-M_2-80mm-PCIe-3_0-x4-3D1-TLC) drive and hence I was unable to proceed with my installation. I found that Lenovo has released BIOS that supports Linux installation (detecting SSD drive) i.e.:

[image: Img]

My current BIOS version is 3HCN14WW. According to logic, it might be newer than the listed BIOS in the website since 14 > 13 and hence I am afraid to update my BIOS.

How can I install Linux on this machine?

Comment: Since you have already update to a newer version of BIOS at the time Lenovo added support for Linux in BIOS, you might receive this error: `ERROR182 - BIOS image is equal or older than ROM!`

Comment: With regards to my comment above, you can actually enable "BIOS Back Flash" in BIOS to flash an older version of BIOS.